# Include axes labels when saving plot from MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have written the following code to try and retrieve ONLY the axes and its plot from my MATLAB GUI.

```
F = getframe(gca);
figure();
image(F.cdata);
saveas(gcf,'PlotPic','png');
close(gcf);
```

I noticed, however, that this method does not include ANY of my axis labels or title. Is there any way which I can get the `getframe` function to include the axis labels and title?

I tried the following code but it did exactly the same

```
pl = plot(x,y);
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')

ftmp = figure;
atmp = axes;
copyobj(pl,atmp);
saveas(ftmp,'PlotPic.png');
delete(ftmp);
```

Comment: What if you use the current figure's handle instead of the current axes? Eg `F = getframe(gcf)` instead of `F= getframe(gca)` . That's supposed to capture labels and the titles, however in a GUI that might cause trouble.

Comment: I tried that, but it causes it to save the entire GUI figure and not just the axes :(

Comment: Have a look at my answer I think I solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it using the `rect` option of the `getframe` function.

Basically you can provide a 2nd input argument to `getframe`, which then captures the content of the rectangle specified as argument. The nice thing is that you can use the handles to an axes, so it does not capture your whole GUI figure but rather a specific axes.

For example, using this line:

```
F = getframe(gca,RectanglePosition);
```

Concretely, you could set the coordinates of the rectangle such that they span both axis labels and the title as well. Here is a sample code. The pushbutton callback executes `getframe` and opens a new figure with the content of `F.cdata`:

```
function GUI_GetFrame
clc
clear
close all

%// Create GUI components
hFigure = figure('Position',[100 100 500 500],'Units','Pixels');

handles.axes1 = axes('Units','Pixels','Position',[60,90,400,300]);
handles.Button = uicontrol('Style','Push','Position',[200 470 60 20],'String','Get frame','Callback',@(s,e) GetFrameCallback);

%// Just create a dummy plot to illustrate
handles.Period = 2*pi;
handles.Frequency = 1/handles.Period;

handles.x = 0:pi/10:2*pi;
handles.y = rand(1)*sin(handles.Period.*handles.x);

plot(handles.x,handles.y,'Parent',handles.axes1)
title('This is a nice title','FontSize',18);
guidata(hFigure,handles); %// Save handles structure of GUI.

    function GetFrameCallback(~,~)

        handles = guidata(hFigure);
        %// Get the position of the axes you are interested in. The 3rd and
        %// 4th coordinates are useful (width and height).

        AxesPos = get(handles.axes1,'Position');    

        %// Call getframe with a custom rectangle size.You might need to change this.
        F = getframe(gca,[-30 -30 AxesPos(3)+50 AxesPos(4)+80]);

        %// Just to display the result
        figure()
        imshow(F.cdata)        
    end
end
```

The GUI looks like this:

[image]

And once I press the pushbutton, this is the figure that pops up:

[image]

So the only trouble you have is to figure out the dimensions of the rectangle you need to select to capture the axis labels and the title.

Hope that solves your problem!